# Keeping a UIButton selected while audio is playing

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift3

I created the button with Image on MainStoryBoard. When I press that button it plays audio file.

I would like that button to stay highlighted during the time audio file is playing. When the audio is finished, I want the button to return to its default state.

I discovered that `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_:successfully:)` is a right way, but can not solve this problem. Is it close to the proper way to do it? If not, how should I?

I'd appreciate any advice that will lead to finding the solution to this problem. Thanks.

```
  let url = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("audio1.mp3")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func play(url: URL) {
    do {
        try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
        player.play()

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

@IBAction func pushButton1(sender: UIButton) {
    play(url: url)
}
```

Comment: Your approach sounds good to me. What's the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On **viewDidLoad**,  you can set default property when it is not playing (eg: I'm keeping background color as white) and while playing, make that button as selected(eg: I'm making it color Green)

Again in **audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying** when it stops playing audio, make it to default state (green to white again):

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourButton: UIButton!
let url = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("audio1.mp3")

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

    self.yourButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white  // default state of button
}

@IBAction func pushButton1(sender: UIButton) {

    play(url: url)
}

func play(url: URL) {

    do {
        try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
        player.play()
        self.yourButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green // playing
    } 
   catch {
       print(error)
    }
}

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer!, successfully flag: Bool) {

    self.yourButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white // back to default state
}
```

Comment: background color i just gave you as an example, you can set your required property there like border color, shadow or something which will make it heighlighted. So instead of colors, change the button property

Comment: Thanks this is the approach I needed, but as I edited above the button color does not back to default state

Comment: did you check by putting breakpoint in audioPlayerDidFinish method whether it is calling or not?